# Dropdown menu changing text in another div

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu inside one div, and when selecting an option it changes text inside another div. So far I can only get it to work inside the same div, using angularJS. How do I fix this? Should I be using a different technique?

head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<div ng-app="dominant" ng-controller="Ctrldominant">

<select ng-model="dominantie">
<option ng-repeat="x in dominantie1" value="{{x.model}}">{{x.model}}</option>
</select>

<p><span id="dominantie-p">{{dominantie}}</span></p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('dominant', []);
app.controller('Ctrldominant', function($scope) {
    $scope.dominantie1 = [
        {model : "Rechts-dominant"},
        {model : "Links-dominant"},
        {model : "Co-dominant"}
    ];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify Controller to the parent element. As the controller directive is added to `<body>`, it is applicable to both divs.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="dominant" ng-controller="Ctrldominant">
      <div>
         <select ng-model="dominantie">
            <option ng-repeat="x in dominantie1" value="{{x.model}}">{{x.model}}</option>
         </select>
         <select ng-model="dominantie2">
            <option ng-repeat="x in dominantie1" value="{{x.model}}" >{{x.model}}</option>
         </select>
         <p><span id="dominantie-p">{{dominantie}}</span></p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p>Second Div: 
            <span id="dominantie-d">{{dominantie}}</span>
            {{dominantie2}}
         </p>
      </div>
      <script>
         var app = angular.module('dominant', []);
         app.controller('Ctrldominant', function($scope) {
            $scope.dominantie1 = [
                {model : "Rechts-dominant"},
                {model : "Links-dominant"},
                {model : "Co-dominant"}
            ];
          });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Saravanan Sachi. Your solution works, however if I wanted multiple dropdowns in the first div, and multiple textchanges in the 2nd div, I think I will have a problem as I can't put multiple controllers in the <body>. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Modified the code for two drop downs in the same controller. Any specific reason to have separate controllers for each drop down?

Comment: No specific reason. What I'm trying to achieve is 2 (or more) dropdowns with different content, and them changing different pieces of text on another piece of the website. So the first dropdown is (rechts-dominant, links-dominant, co-dominant) and the second could be (apple, pear, orange). They would control different pieces of text. It is probably a small adjustment from your last code, I hope i'm more clear now. Thanks  a lot